# Dynamic values for SQL in JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp, jstl

I am trying to pass the value from one sql query in JSP Page to another insert query in the same page. Can someone help me with the syntax.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<sql:query var="ID" dataSource="jdbc/myDatasource">
    SELECT max(id) as maxid FROM table1
</sql:query>

<sql:update var="upd" dataSource="jdbc/myDatasource" >
    INSERT INTO table2 (name, fk_t2) values ('<%=text%>', Value returned from the above select query)        
</sql:update>
```

I tried passing the variable ID as the paramater but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the values obtained from the first query into the variable and use it for the second query as,

```
<sql:query var="ID" dataSource="jdbc/myDatasource">
    SELECT max(id) as maxid FROM table1
</sql:query>
```

Iterate the resultset with `<c:forEach>` loop ,

```
   <c:forEach var="row" items="${ID.rows}">
     <c:set var="maxId" value="${row.maxid}"/>
   </c:forEach>
```

And using  `<sql:param>` tag ,

```
<sql:update var="upd" dataSource="jdbc/myDatasource" >
    INSERT INTO table2 (name, fk_t2) values ('<%=text%>',?)  
    <sql:param value="${maxId}" />      
</sql:update>
```

Comment: It gives the error "Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException" when id pass "ID" as value in c:set. If I pass maxid as value in c:set it passes the value as NULL

Comment: Have you checked what the first query returned using the `<c:out>` after executing the first query

Comment: It gives org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.ResultImpl@6e633ab6.

I was expecting it to return the one value i.e., the maxid